# How can I insert a ">" in a quoted knockout area in a MVC .cshtml file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have the following:

```
<select id="countries" 
   data-bind='
      options: selectedContinent() ? countries : null, 
      optionsValue : "Id", 
      optionsText: "Name", 
      optionsCaption: "[Please select a country]", 
      value: selectedCountry,
      visible: (countries() && countries().length > 0)'>
</select>
```

Unfortunately this shows an error in the IDE that's caused by the ">" on the last line of the data-bind.  Is there a way that I can escape this so it will not show an error?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting the data-bind attribute in double quotes, and the values inside the attribute in single quotes? You might also need to have the first value of it starting on the same line too:

```
<select id="countries" 
   data-bind="options: selectedContinent() ? countries : null, 
      optionsValue : 'Id', 
      optionsText: 'Name', 
      optionsCaption: '[Please select a country]', 
      value: selectedCountry,
      visible: (countries() && countries().length > 0)">
</select>
```

Comment: I do this as well in Razor files: use double quotes for the outer boundaries and single quotes for anything within.  It should work fine.